# google-cloud/pubsub v.4.1.0 in react

Tags: reactjs, google-cloud-pubsub

I'm wanting to use `@google-cloud/pubsub` in react but I get this error:

[console error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZJEaB.png)

This is my code:

```
import { PubSub } from '@google-cloud/pubsub';
const projectId = import.meta.env.VITE_REACT_APP_PUB_SUB_PROJECT_ID;
const topicId = import.meta.env.VITE_REACT_APP_PUB_SUB_TOPIC_ID;
const subName = import.meta.env.VITE_REACT_APP_PUB_SUB_NAME;


 const quickstartPubSub = async () => {
    const pubsub = new PubSub({ projectId: projectId });
    const [topic] = await pubsub.createTopic(topicId);
    const [subscription] = await topic.createSubscription(subName);

    subscription.on('message', (message) => {
      console.log('Received message:', message.data.toString());
      process.exit(0);
    });

    subscription.on('error', (error) => {
      console.error('Received error:', error);
      process.exit(1);
    });

    await topic.publish(Buffer.from('Test message!'));
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    quickstartPubSub()
  }, [])
```

Try using:

```
const {PubSub} = require('@google-cloud/pubsub')
grpc
```